fast fetch al iniciar kitty
Estaba tratando de hacer que al abrir mi terminal en Kali Linux (usando kitty) se ejecutara automáticamente el comando fastfetch, pero no funciono. Intenté simplemente añadir "fastfetch" al archivo de configuración de kitty, pero no hizo nada. Después probé con la ruta completa del comando, pero tampoco funcionó. Incluso volví a la terminal por defecto, pero el resultado fue el mismo: fastfetch no se ejecutaba al abrir la terminal. Pensé que podría ser un problema de permisos, así que intenté el chmod +x /usr/local/bin/fastfetch, pero eso tampoco hizo nada

qué pasa si ejecutas el comando a mano en el shell?

Si quieres que se ejecute solo cuando abres kitty (y no cada vez que abres una nueva tab/window) puedes usar un archivo de configuración de sesión:

Abre kitty.conf (~/.config/kitty/kitty.conf) y agrega/edita la linea:
startup_session session.conf


Crea un archivo session.conf (~/.config/kitty/session.conf) y agrega la línea:
launch --hold fastfetch



No te olvides de la opción --hold o la terminal se cerrará tras ejecutar fastfetch. Puedes crear/nombrar el archivo como y donde quieras, solo indica la ruta correcta en startup_session.
